# Comparison function in c++ error: invalid comparator

Tags: c++, function, comparison

I made a simple comaprison function that looks like this:

```
bool function(int a, int b){
    if (a % 2 == 0) {
        return (a > b);
    }
    if (a % 2 == 1) {
        return (a < b);
    }
    return false;
}
```

My main function looks like this:

```
int main() {
    vector<int> vector = {8, 4, 4, 8, 4, 1, 4, 4, 6, 10, 12 };

    sort(vector.begin(), vector.end(), function);

    cout << endl;
    for (int i : vector) {
        cout << i << " ";
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The function should arrange an array so that all even numbers are in one part of the array and
all odd numbers are in another part of that array.

When I try to run the code, it gives me the error "invalid comparator". Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Please provide [mre], with **copy-pasted** error messages. For instance: which line produces the error "invalid comparator"?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius It doesen't tell me witch line of my code causes the problem, but the error looks like this: C:/UNREAL/install/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/include/xutility
Line: 1618

Expression: invalid comparator

Comment: @drianHEY Then, my request still stands: please provide [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you used this comparator in `std::sort`. Then it must satisfy the requirement [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare):

> For all a, `comp(a,a)==false`

Ok, your comparator will always return `false` for equal values.

> If `comp(a,b)==true` then `comp(b,a)==false`

That one fails:

- `function(1, 2) == true`, so 1 should come before 2, but ...
- `function(2, 1) == true`, so 2 should come before 1, whoops.

> if `comp(a,b)==true` and `comp(b,c)==true` then `comp(a,c)==true`

That one fails to: `function(2, 1)==true`, `function(1, 3)==true`, but `function(2, 3)==false`.

---

This code should achieve what you want:

```cpp
bool function(int a, int b){
    if(a % 2 == b % 2) {
        // If both are even or both are odd simply compare the numbers
        return a < b;
    } 
    else {
        // if one is even and the other is odd then
        // a should come before b if a is even
        return a % 2 == 0; 
    }
}
```

Sorting `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]` will result in `[ 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, ]`

Answer (score 0):

The other answer explains the problem and provides a solution assuming the halves of the resulting array have to be sorted.

If they aren't, you can use a more simple comparator: `return a % 2 < b % 2`. Then you should also use `std::partition` instead of `std::sort` (since it's potentially faster), or `std::stable_partition` if you want to maintain the original order.